# Find string elements in matrix from list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to search for string values that I have in a n x n matrix to see if they exist in a list. The output should be a n x n matrix with boolean True or False depending if the string was found. The matrix and the list look like this:

```
matrix = [['aa', 'ba', 'ca'], ['ab', 'bb', 'cb'], ['ac', 'bc', 'cc']]
list = ['ba','cb','dg']
```

I have this code:

```
matrixFound = [[for x in matrix] for y in matrix]
```

and I would need to somehow include this statement elementwise:

```
matrix in list
```

The output should be a matrix like this:

```
[[False,True,False],[False,False,True],[False,False,False]]
```

I was thinking of using map or lambda to solve this but cannot get the coding right.
How should this be done? Regular python or numpy could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy's isin:

```
np.isin(matrix,list2)                                                                                                                                                               

# array([[False,  True, False],
#       [False, False,  True],
#       [False, False, False]])
```

Answer (score 1):

With numpy it's absolutely trivial:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: matrix = numpy.array([['aa', 'ba', 'ca'], ['ab', 'bb', 'cb'], ['ac', 'bc', 'cc']])

In [3]: matrix == 'cb'
Out[3]:
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [4]: search = ['ba','cb','dg']

In [5]: result = numpy.zeros(matrix.shape, dtype='bool')

In [6]: result
Out[6]:
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [7]: for s in search:
   ...:     result |= matrix == s
   ...:

In [8]: result
Out[8]:
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: What advantage does this have over `numpy.isin`?

Comment: I didn't think of `numpy.isin` to be honest :) The advantage of this method is that it's at least clear how to write variants of `numpy.isin` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code you are looking for if you want to use list comprehension.
`matrixFound = [[x in list for x in y] for y in matrix]`
It simulates nested loop where the outer comprehension chooses a column from `matrix`, and the inner one checks whether the elements are in `list`

Comment: Thanks for this non-nympy solution. A little bit slower than the numpy version but very useful.

Comment: To speed this up a bit, convert `list` to a `set()`